# Is it possible to combine Google's Web Speech API with a non web application?

Tags: javascript, python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to write a simple "Siri" like program in `Python` that'll accept voice commands after a keyword is said and execute something in response.

I was wondering if I could use Google's Web Speech `Javascript` API for this.

I read that there is a 60 second limit on the Speech Recognition and so I plan on doing the keyword detection using PocketSphinx and have the `javascript` Google Web Speech called in response to it to handle the rest of the Speech Recognition.

Since I have 0 experience in Web Development and Javascript in particular, I was wondering if it is possible to use the Web Speech API in a non browser environment. i.e I'd like to be able to run the code on the client solely for the Speech Recognition in response to a `Python` method being called and receive the Speech Recognition's output.

From what I understand this means executing a `javascript` code in response to a `python` function and getting the `javascript` return value back.

So is it possible to:

1. Use the Javascript API in a non browser environment to run the Speech Recognition
2. Get the return value from the javascript code back as a return value from a `python` method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to javascript API from a python interpreter, Javascript API runs in web browser. Instead, you can just access same Google's speech recognition through the web API with HTTP requests.

You just send requests to the server with a POST and get results back.

See for example https://github.com/Seraf/LISA and https://github.com/jasperproject, both are running Python and access Google when needed.

Comment: Is this an official Google API?

Comment: If you want something fast, reliable and stable, it's better to use pocketsphinx api for everything, it's accurate for many practical cases.

Comment: And, there is nothing official from google. They open and close APIs every day so you can't rely on them just like on any SaaS platform. If you are looking on Saas specifically, you might want to check http://wit.ai

Comment: I'm currently using it and it doesn't really fit my needs. I've tried using the HTTP request with the Google link a few weeks back and it stopped responding to the request after a few weeks. I assumed they shut it down or something of that sort. That's why I want to know if there is an official API I can use. So is there one?

Comment: By "it" I mean Pocketsphinx. Wit.ai looks interesting. I'll check it out

Comment: Well, unlike for Google, you always have an option to improve pocketsphinx speech recognition accuracy for your tasks. To do that you need to collect testing data as described at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq/#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor

Comment: I've given `Pocketsphinx` a try and it seems to have poor recognition out of the box (i.e the matches are wrong 90% of the time). Is it supposed to be this way or could it be I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are doing something wrong. Since you didn't provide the details it's hard to say what you did wrong exactly.